# Is it possible to run Navigation stack in tracked robot?

Tags: mobile-robot, navigation, mobile-base, amcl, move-base

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want a build a multi-terrain self-navigation vehicle. I had designed a tracked(belted wheel) robot which will be suitable for my application.

Now is it possible to run ROS navigation stack in a tracked robot? if so, will that work properly with the same efficiency as differential drive wheeled robot?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/251072/is-it-possible-to-run-navigation-stack-in-tracked-robot?/) by [Kishore Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/20863/kishore-kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 173 on 2017-01-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ubicray](https://answers.ros.org/users/31004/ubicray/) on 2017-07-03**:
I'm wondering about the same question. Any updates on your progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Tracked platforms tend to slip when they turn, so odometry on them is usually somewhere between poor and useless.

AMCL and most other localization techniques require some variety of pose update to work well, and usually that's provided by odometry. You may want to consider providing a pose estimate from some other source such as an IMU or visual odometry.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-01-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1